# Paytm "networkError"

Tags: android, paytm

I have tried implementing  Paytm using both the approaches ("Standard Checkout" and "All-in-One SDK" ) but  my transaction page or Paytm App never opens for the payment and I am getting networkError inside onActivityResult

I have successfully  generated checksum and TransactionToken on my node server but on passing the TxnToken to paytm sdk nothing is happening.

Any thought why is this happening ?

Comment: I am also getting the same error.

Comment: I contacted Paytm Support later, they game me
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LsgHdcRjcgCqaqo-JGUdbX5fAHIxyLzF/view?ts=5e87315f
this example which work but only in paytm initiated web-flow.

Comment: Getting the same error. no resolution from PayTm

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: No, I had to compromise with paytm initiated web-flow.

Comment: did any one solve this ?

Comment: any one have solved this? @HritikGupta

Comment: Not yet, Paytm team is not very responsive on this error.

Comment: @HritikGupta please check my answer it is working now.

Comment: @ZalaKrunal please check my answer

Comment: @Prakhar1001 please check my answer

Comment: @NagvadiyaVishal please check my answer

Comment: same error i faced when i integrate in flutter.@HritikGupta

Answer (score 3):

I got solution to "Network error"

As I did not found solution to this error I mailed to support team and they have replied me following

Prerequisite:
UNINSTALL existing paytm app before installing from below link.

Paytm Staging: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BfvEa04KStQ0WDGG9L4Fd75lKJlrp1X9/view?usp=sharing

Login Credentials:
Username:- 7777777777
Password:- Paytm12345
https://developer.paytm.com/docs/all-in-one-sdk/

It is working for me.

Thanks to Paytm support team for quick and correct reply.

Comment: Thank for your ans. I will check but i found this error only in test mode, in production mode its work perfectly.

Comment: Yes exactly for stage mode we need to user paytm App for stage only

Comment: I have also checked with Paytm Support, I also got same ans.

Comment: same error i faced when i integrate in flutter.